# Key Exchange Protocol attack

Tags: cryptography

I am working on the exercise below which ask about whether it is possible to attack the following key exchange protocol on sharing session key $K_s$ between user $X$ and $Y$:

1. $X \rightarrow Y  : X \| r$
2. $Y \rightarrow X  : E (r \| K_s, K_{xy})$
3. $X \rightarrow Y  : E (r, K_s)$

where $K_{xy}$ is a pre-shared secret key between user $X$ and $Y$, $K_s$ is a session key, $E(m, k)$ is symmetric key encryption on message $m$, with key $k$

It appears to me that it is secure. Could any one can give me a hand or some hints on possible attack ?

Comment: How does $Y$ know the $r$ in order to carry out step 2?

Comment: @user10354138 It's sent in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in this protocol.

1. An attacker can start the protocol instead of $X$ since the id $X$ sent unencrypted and the attacker can generate a random $r$. $Y$ generates the key sends back to $X$. In the first hand, there is no rejection for $Y$
2. The attacker can store all transmitted $E (r \| K_s, K_{xy})$ and transmitted encrypted messages with $K_{s_i}$for a future usage. When he successfully attacked one of the $X$ and $Y$, he can decrypt all the messages first by decrypting the stored $E (r \| K_s, K_{xy})$. In short, this protocol has no [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy).